# Are there practical applications for boson sampling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-computer, bosons

[Boson sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson_sampling) is a computation that is not doable on classical machines but quite doable on quantum photonic machines.

[image]

[image]

(https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Experimental-results-for-3-and-4-boson-sampling-A-B-The-equivalent-3-and-4-boson_fig2_301872712)

The precise generated pattern at the end of the board will take impossibly long to compute/simulate on classical machines.

However, just being a computation that is not doable by classical machines does not seem too rare or special... Classical computers cannot fully simulate the brain of a six-year-old for even a microsecond either.

So are there any practical applications for being able to perform boson sampling, other than doing a computation that classical machines cannot do?

Comment: One can't compute Maxwell's equations numerically for such a field geometry in finite time with useful accuracy? I very, very much doubt that. There is absolutely nothing quantum mechanical in this setup as far as I can see. As long as we are only interested in the intensity of the diffraction pattern at the output this is trivial. OTOH, if we are doing this experimentally, then all we ever get is a photon frequency rather than a probability and that certainly can't have "infinite precision", either. As presented by your question this looks very much like intellectual nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

BosonSampling is a toy problem that enables quantum computers to demonstrate "quantum supremacy" over classical computers.

I would view it as an invention to help define a milestone for quantum computers to reach, that is not trivial, but not as hard as building a large fault-tolerant quantum computer capable of factoring large numbers. The problem itself was invented *because* there's an efficient way to do it on a quantum computer and not on a classical computer; there is no external application of the problem outside of quantum computing that I am aware of.

Comment: Except that the problem does not even have a stable optical realization that can reproduce a result. So what they are suggesting here is at most an example of a problem that can't be implemented on a quantum computer, either.

Comment: @FlatterMann https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abe8770

Comment: Key word in the abstract of that paper is "76-photon coincidence". That is not what is shown in the OP question. And even then I would have to question the dependence of the result on the optical properties of the source.

Comment: @FlatterMann In the context of theoretical (and now experimental) quantum computing, [Boson sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson_sampling) is a technical term referring to the kind of algorithm described in that abstract.

Comment: Fair, but that is not what is shown in the image by the OP. A 76-photon coincidence experiment is absolutely nothing like an optical Galton-board. I would also have to ask where the 76 entangled photons came from because photons from a trivial light source are not entangled. They are completely independent.

Comment: @FlatterMann it is the interferometer that entangles the photons: you cannot know which of the photons is detected at particular position.  Please read on the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect to see how the entangle enters into the simple 2-photon HOM interference.

Comment: Would it in principle, boson sampling allow to calculate the modulus square of the permanent of a given unitary matrix?

Comment: @Mauricio yes but that would be a poor use of the resources because the probability of getting 1 photon per detector (which is the output that gives the permanent) is *very* low (exponentially low IIRC) for a large network.  So you’d have to wait forever *and then some* to get any kind of meaningful statistics to estimate the permanent.  Hence the idea of simulating the *distribution* of photons of a submatrix of a unitary.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Photons of different energy can't be entangled that way. It takes a sufficiently coherent source to do these experiments. That was my point that without a "special" source none of this works. So, no, it is not "the interferometer" that does this. It is always a phenomenon between quantum effects at the source and quantum effects at the detector. The interferometers are always just linear mappings that change phases. I believe this is greatly misunderstood in the linear optics community.

Comment: @FlatterMann Unfortunately your comment simply illustrates your lack of understanding of the situation.  Experiments *have been done* by multiple groups using good-sized network, and sources (quantum dots in particular) are now available that produce multiple photons with enough coherence allow experiments with several tens of photons.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero No offense, but it is easy to tell me that I don't understand. It is probably not quite so easy to prove that these experiments are actually reproducible. Don't bother to find references. I know how to do my own literature search. And, by the way... one of the high energy physics detectors I worked on during my active life did coincidence on up to thousands of photons. I even wrote a fast detection algorithm for it. So please don't tell me that I don't know how all of this works. That is just simple collegial courtesy. Peace!

Comment: @FlatterMann Since there are published papers (including in Science) claiming to have done precisely this experiment, if you have a proof that these experiments are not reproducible, then I suggest you write a rebuttal paper. I'm sure that a paper would be of great interest to the community, certainly more than comments here.

Comment: @Andrew Experiments with photons are notoriously hard. Experiments in linear optics which can not rely on energy separation are much, much harder still. Many linear quantum optics papers are missing the very documentation needed to understand how exactly systematic errors were controlled. If you want to see how the relevant scientific documentation really looks like, the CERN document servers contain tens, if not hundreds of thousand of pages of information on the many checks and cross checks that were done to actually operate LHC and its detectors. That I trust because I can see the work.

Answer (score 3):

BosonSampling itself does not appear to have any application.  Aaronson and Arkhipov were always clear about this.  In this sense in a toy problem.

The interest is because simulating (exactly or approximately) the distribution of $n$ photons at the output of the interferometer is “extremely hard” for a classical computer, but “easy” for the interferometer, which functions in this case as a specialized single-task quantum computer.  In other words, it is likely possible to soon perform an experiment where a specialized quantum computer (the interferometer) outperforms any classical computer.  It’s not the only example of a problem that cannot be easily handled by a classical computer, but it’s one for which there’s an experiment, which can be done in the near future, that will show a “quantum advantage” of a system over a classical computer.

There’s a variant called  Gaussian BosonSampling which uses squeezers and unitaries manipulate Gaussian states.  Gaussian BosonSampling is equally hard as BosonSampling and somewhat easier experimentally.  Incredibly, it seems there are applications to Gaussian BosonSampling; some are surveyed in

> Bromley, Thomas R., et al. "Applications of near-term photonic quantum computers: software and algorithms." *Quantum Science and Technology* 5.3 (2020): 034010.

(There are probably other applications: the field is moving reasonably fast.)

—————

For the purpose fo completeness, the difficulty of BosonSampling is in summing the scattering amplitudes for a particular set of positions of the $n$ detectors.  These amplitudes actually work out to be permanents of complex random matrices, and the number of operations needed to evaluate a permanent grows *exponentially* with the number of photons.

Additionally, BosonSampling is not about computing a single permanent, i.e. a particular amplitude.  It’s about the distribution of such (modulus squared of) permanents.  The counting rate for a particular set of positions of detectors decreases with the size of the network, so one would wait extremely long to accumulate enough statistics to get a reasonable number counts for this particular position of detectors.

Comment: It is not "easy" for the interferometer, either. People simply don't calculate the actual numbers of photons that would really be necessary to sample the actual wave function in a 100 dimensional Hilbert space. They publish results of measurements with a couple million photons, maybe with a few billion and then they think they understand the entire wave function. That is just horrendous intellectual nonsense.

Comment: @FlatterMann I’m truly sorry to say your comment shows you have extremely limited understanding of how BosonSampling experiments actually work.  To be blunt: nobody detects a million photons, or claims to detect that much in a run.  Indeed photons are detected individually in each detector.  The dimension of Hilbert space is also *much larger* than 100: more like $10^{14}$.  See https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.123.250503?casa_token=8U7PRQA0t4cAAAAA%3ArztbDAHc23F_0wqCVbkukNrOHpkKNqv1THWyX2EbtdKUV2g0Bl7M_ya15upBJ41eHs6bol2qHHAEog

Comment: So you are saying there are no statistical errors in quantum measurements? How does one sample a 10^30 dimensional space with 10^6 quanta? Now, that is obviously not what boson sampling does. So what does it do to arrive at reproducible results? It measures correlations with large numbers of quanta. Would these, by any chance, be nearly classical subspaces of the whole Hilbert space since n=76 as mentioned in one experiment, is already suggesting classical behavior?

Comment: @FlatterMann   detecting single photons individually is not classical.

Comment: No, it's not, but if you have many photons, then you start seeing classical waves. There is another obvious problem here: single photon detectors have quantum efficiencies of typically 70%. So if we are detecting coincidences of lets say 70 photons, then there were, on average, really 100 photons. This means that what we are detecting is not a single state with n=70 but a mix of states with maybe 70<n<130 or so. Since the argument is that one can't calculate the theoretical result with classical means, there is no actual prediction that one could compare this measured mixed state to.

Comment: @FlatterMann sorry this is not constructive.  Please read any one of the many experimental papers.  The early ones with few photons were done circa 2013, and the procedure is clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140396/discussion-between-flattermann-and-zerothehero).

Answer (score 1):

Boson sampling is a famous "useless" problem but in fact there are a couple areas of practical applications. One is for Proof-of-Work consensus, wherein a network of adversarial players without centralized authority want to reach consensus, e.g. to verify transactions on a distributed ledger. Making verifiers prove they performed some computation before transactions are approved counters attacks like double spending. A usual classical Proof-of-Work problem for blockchain applications is inverse hashing (also an otherwise useless problem) and a protocol using coarse grained boson sampling to achieve the same affect is given here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.19865
This approach basically uses the fact that the full distribution is hard to simulate classically, but a suitable coarse grained distribution can be validated classically.

Another area of application is for graph problems. Gaussian boson sampling can identify dense subgraphs with high probability:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10730
or identify graph invariants
https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/spma-2020-0132/html?lang=en